# Urn with $4$ Different Colored Balls that is Drawn $4$ Times with Replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

There is an urn that contains $1$ Green ball, $1$ Red ball, $1$ White ball, and $1$ Yellow ball.

The urn is drawn 4 times with replacement. So

I am trying to calculate:

the probability of the the 4 draws yielding exactly 2 pairs of colors (e.g. GGRR)

and

the probability of the 4 draws yielding 1 single pair of color and 2 single / different colors (e.g. GGRW)

For the 2 pairs, my thinking is such that

${4\choose2}$ represents the numbers of ways a paired color combo can be drawn / arranged

${4\choose1}$ is for the 1st color of the paired color combo

${3\choose1}$ is for the 2nd color of the paired color combo

${16\choose4}$ is for the total number of possible slots (_ _ _ _, each _ being a possible of 4 colors)

$$\frac{{4\choose2}{4\choose1}{3\choose1}}{16\choose4}$$

I am not sure if this is right, but I think I am at least somewhat on the right track

For the 1 pair + 2 singles, in all honesty, I am bit lost about how to begin. I am not sure whether I should use the nCk formula or go by counting and then adjust for slot placement.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to MSE.  This is a good first post.  It's clearly stated, and you've shown your work.  Unfortunately, there are some problems with the math.

The event space can be taken to be the set of $4$-element sequences from the letters G,R,W,Y.  There are $4^4=256$ of these, since each of the $4$ elements of the sequence has $4$ possible values.  Now for the first problem, there are $\binom42=6$ pairs of colors.  How many sequences can we make with them?  By the formula for permutations with repetitions, this is $\frac{4!}{2!2!}=6$, so the probability is $$\frac{36}{256}=\frac9{64}$$

Can you do the second problem now?

Comment: I believe I can. I did it by 4! / (1! 3!) to get the number of single pairs multiplied by 3! / (2! 1!) to account for the 2 single duo and then multiplied that by the permutation formula for a single pair case, which gives me 144 ways (out of 256). I think this method is in line with your explanation. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @passerby If this answer solved your problem, you should accept it by clicking the check mark, so that it no longer shows as unresolved.

Answer (score 1):

If you say there are $4^4=256$ equally likely ways of drawing the balls, then the number of ways of drawing them with  patterns of

- $4,0,0,0$ is $\frac{4!}{1!3!}\frac{4!}{4!0!0!0!}=4$
- $3,1,0,0$ is $\frac{4!}{1!1!2!}\frac{4!}{3!1!0!0!}=48$
- $2,2,0,0$ is $\frac{4!}{2!2!}\frac{4!}{2!2!0!0!}=36$
- $2,1,1,0$ is $\frac{4!}{1!2!1!}\frac{4!}{2!1!1!0!}=144$
- $1,1,1,1$ is $\frac{4!}{4!}\frac{4!}{1!1!1!1!}=24$

which add up to $256$

So the answers to your questions are $\dfrac{36}{256}=\dfrac{9}{64}$ and $\dfrac{144}{256}=\dfrac{9}{16}$

Comment: Hi. I found this be very helpful as it is very systematic, but am having issues on some parts, namely the 3,1,0,0 and 2,1,1,0 cases. My understanding of your notation is that, for example, 4,0,0,0 means that color 1 (whatever it may be) is repeated 4 time. The right hand uses the permutation with repetition formula and the left hand uses the combinatorial formula to account for the 4 colors (please correct me if I am wrong). However, I am not understanding the 4! / (1! 1! 2!) for the 3,1,0,0 case and the 4! / (2!, 1!, 1!, 0!)  for the 2,1,1,0 case. Would you be please explain a bit? TY.

Comment: @passerby for the $3,1,0,0$ case you get $4! / (1! 1! 2!)$  on the left  as there is $1$ three and $1$ one and $2$ zeros, together with ${4!}/(3!1!0!0!)$ on the right to match  $3,1,0,0$.  Similarly for the $2,1,1,0$ case you get ${4!}/({1!2!1!})$  on the left  as there is $1$ two and $2$ ones and $1$ zero, together with $4! / (2!, 1!, 1!, 0!) $ on the right to match $2,1,1,0$.

Comment: I guess I am not understanding what the left side is formula wise / conceptually does and/or represent. I had thought the left hand utilized the combination formula nCk, but by your explanation that is not the case. I am really sorry to keep bothering you, but would you please explain why the left hand side is calculated such conceptually? Thank you.

Comment: For $3,1,0,0$  you have  ${4 \choose 1}$ ways of choosing the colour of the $3$ and conditionally on that ${3 \choose 1}$ ways of choosing the colour of the $1$ and  ${2 \choose 2}$ ways of choosing the colours of the two $0$s.  And  ${4 \choose 1}{3 \choose 1}{2 \choose 2}=\frac{4!}{1!1!2!}$.  Similarly for $2,1,1,0$  you have  ${4 \choose 1}$ ways of choosing the colour of the $2$ and conditionally on that ${3 \choose 2}$ ways of choosing the colours of the two $1$s and ${1 \choose 1}$ ways of choosing the colour of the $0$.  And ${4 \choose 1}{3 \choose 2}{1 \choose 1}=\frac{4!}{1!2!1!}$.